# WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
robert@robert-Lenovo-E31-80:~$ какая -то хрень                                         

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'
```

Случайно написал бессмыслицу и вылезло это...Пугает очень.

```
robert@robert-Lenovo-E31-80:~$ bash /etc/apt/sources.list                                               
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Отказано в доступе
```

Опасно ли это и как исправить?

**Added**

```
$ ls -l /etc/apt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 дек 25 23:54 sources.list -> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
drw-r--r-- 2 root root 4096 дек 25 16:45 sources.list.d

$ ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/..': Отказано в доступе
ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/.': Отказано в доступе
итого 0 
d????????? ? ? ? ? ? . 
d????????? ? ? ? ? ? ..
```

Comment: посмотри/покажи права доступа... скорей всего не хватает `chmod u+rw`

Comment: drwxrwxr-x  2 robert robert      4096 мая 30  2018  backup
-rw-r--r--  1 robert robert         0 окт  6 17:46  code.py
-rw-r--r--  1 robert robert        37 мая 25  2018  coding.c
-rw-r--r--  1 robert robert       536 авг 23 05:12  control.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 robert robert 154528244 авг 23 05:16  data.tar.xz
-rw-r--r--  1 robert robert         4 авг 23 05:12  debian-binary
drwxr-xr-x  2 robert robert      4096 июл 19 19:06  Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  8 robert robert      4096 сен 28 17:18  Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 robert robert      4096 июл 19 19:06  Downloads

Comment: Оно?,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: во-первых, вывод в вопрос — есть кнопка «править», а во-вторых права на /etc/source.list, а не домашний каталог: `ls -al /etc/apt`...

Comment: Извините,я просто недавно стал учить линукс,да и на стэке недавно...                                                  lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    58 дек 25 23:54 sources.list -> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
drw-r--r--   2 root root  4096 дек 25 16:45 sources.list.d

Comment: ничего страшного... ещё раз, выводы лучше добавлять прямо в вопрос с помощью маленькой серой кнопки «править»... и ещё для полноты картины, что выводит `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/..': Отказано в доступе                           
ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/.': Отказано в доступе                             
итого 0                                                                                                                                             
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..

Comment: Попробуй через `sudo`: `sudo ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, после попросит ввести пароль. Если нет такой команды, то нужно авторизоваться под `root`: `su`, после попросит ввести пароль и после вводи команду `ls..`

Comment: Эээ,у меня файл /etc/apt/sources.list полностью пустой,так может быть?

Comment: У вас точно ubuntu? В `/etc/apt` должно быть больше файлов. У каталога `sources.list.d` странные права. Должны быть `drwxr-xr-x`. Можно для начала сделать `sudo chmod a+x /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: Да,ubuntu 18.04.В файле /etc/apt/sources.list вообще ничего нет,это так и должно быть??????????

Comment: Вообще, похоже, что вы благополучно угробили систему (или близки к этому) своими экспериментами, так что проще поставить её заново.

Comment: Дауж,я заигрался.Хочу попробовать что-то другое,что можете посоветовать из дистрибутивов?

Comment: `sources.list` у вас сейчас ссылается на файл к которому нет доступа. Выполните мою команду выше, что бы вернуть доступ, а потом уже можно смотреть дальше.

Comment: Ну я бы посоветовал поставить Ubuntu заново и попробовать понять, что вы делаете, прежде чем бездумно выполнять команды из учебников и прочих странных мест.

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list .: Нет такого файла или каталога

Answer (score 2):

Здесь две проблемы:

- Во-первых, случайно снят флаг исполнения на каталоги `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`; бит исполнения на каталогах позволяет получать доступ к файлам (см. например [это](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0_unix)). Исправляется:

  ```
  sudo chmod a+x /etc/apt/sources.list.d
  ```
- Во-вторых, удалён файл на который ссылался `source.list`. Без оного не получится установить что-либо из из основных репозитариев. Его нужно пересоздать, типовое содержимое примерное такое:

  ```
  deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe multiverse
  deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main universe multiverse
  deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main universe multiverse
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe multiverse
  ```

  Само собой `bionic` нужно заменить на имя своей версии; также, если это не противоречит религиозным убеждениям, возможно захочется добавить [`restricted`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) ветку.

  Также несколько более нудных способов его восстановить описаны, например, [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories).

Как обычно, в проблемах класса ССЗБ возможны и другие ошибки.

Comment: `удалён файл` — он не удалён (наверное), а в том самом каталоге к котому нет доступа.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, не был бы удалён — `ls` его имя показал бы в списке, но не смог бы выполнить для него `stat`.

Comment: Да. Тогда точно угробил.

Comment: @AlexeyTen что угробил?

Comment: Автор вопроса угробил систему. Я сильно подозреваю (особенно с учётом знаний автора), что это не единственная проблема. Наверное систему можно восстановить, но проще переставить с нуля.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, советовать перестанавливать систему (равно как и советовать сделать подобное) из-за удаления одного файла — дремучее невежество ИМХО.

Comment: Там не один файл. Ну и система явно для экспериментов.

Comment: @AlexeyTen *Ten что угробил?* - да ничего он не угробил! Надо восстановить право исполнения на директорию */etc/apt/sources.list.d* (как об этом сказал Fat-Zer), тогда и файлы в этой директории станут доступны!

Comment: @Fat-Zer *удалён файл на который ссылался source.list* - из чего это видно (это - раз). И (это два), то что Вы привели в качестве примера, это не **сылка** а сам содержимое этого файла. И это содержимое, с вероятностью почти 100% одинаково на ВСЕХ компах, где установлена бубунта.

Comment: @Sergey, если бы он не был удалён он был бы виден в выводе `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` даже несмотря на то, что у каталога стоит `-x` (подразумевая конечно, что OP правильно скопировал вывод). (и два) да, всё так и задумано: явно его восстановить... а с кутерьмой по поводу симлинка — похоже это мода новых бубунт, вместо обычного `sources.list` ссылаться на один из файлов в `sources.list.d`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer **он был бы виден в выводе ls  даже несмотря на то, что у каталога стоит -x** - Сначала я Вам просто не поверил. Выдал команду *ls tmp*, потом снял "исполнение" с каталога *tmp* и повторил команду. На каждый элемент каталога выдалось сообщение: *ls: невозможно получить доступ к 'tmp/Sphinx': Отказано в доступе* и всё в таком же духе. Но потом она спокойненько РАСПЕЧАТАЛА содержимое каталога!  Это как же, вашу мать, разрешите понимать ?!!! Раньше такого точно не было. Нет доступа - значит нет доступа.
*

Comment: @Sergey, на самом деле так всегда было=), а `ls --color=none` отработает вообще без ошибок... для чтения списка файлов из каталога выполняется только `opendir()`/`readir()`, т.е. достаточно `+r`; а для получения stat()'ов файлов внутри каталога нужен уже `+x`... Меня всегда забавлял обратный эффект: если установить -r+x, то `ls tmp` полностью провалиться, а ls tmp/Sphinx — отработает нормально... Правда на практике практике раздельная установка битов rx для каталогов, как говориться, используется чуть чаще, чем никогда...

Answer (score 0):

> /etc/apt/sources.list .: Нет такого файла или каталога

Если действительно это так, то вот Вам его содержимое:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http://manpages.ylsoftware.com/debian/ all main
```

Это всего-навсего список репозитариев, на которых лежит дистрибутив бубунты. Единственное, что у Вас может быть другая версия, чем у меня и тогда слово *xenial* надо заменить на соответствующее название Вашего дистрибутива. Они все перечислены вот здесь: http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/